# Reverse Engineer XPath of WebElement

Tags: java, css, regex, xpath

I was wondering if it's possible to reverse engineer the XPath of a WebElement if one of the attributes are known but the path is unknown. For example, suppose the XPath to a certain WebElement is (@id,'vi_main_img_fs_thImg')]/img but this is not known. I know however that this WebElement will return http://myimage.com/72hjf89 (i.e, a unique value) when calling WebElement.getAttribute("src") - is it possible to use the information to "reverse engineer" the original XPath value? Perhaps using Regex or something?

Note: The .getAttribute("src") was only an example, I suppose whatever method works will work no matter what attribute is used as long as this value occurs once on page.

Any ideas?

Update:

To give more detailed example of what I'm trying to achieve I'm copying HTML code below.

The page I am looking at is: http://www.ebay.com/itm/111488868372

The HTML on page is:

```
<document>
<html lang="en" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" webdriver="true">
<head>
<body class=" vi-contv2 lhdr-ie- vi-hd-ops " style="background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAKCAYAAAB10jRKAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAADBJREFUeNpEyqERADAIBMGbbwSH+qhA/6URXMyqBUhFBLIP6ip0ezk2zExqC58nwACVZwX67tO41gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="), url("http://ir.ebaystatic.com/pictures/aw/pics/cmp/ds3/imgbg.jpg"); background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat; background-position: 0px 30px, 0px 0px;">
<div id="gh-gb" tabindex="-1"/>
<!-- Default filmstrip js used with main image -->
<!-- adding filmstrip js used in main pic and with images carousel -->
<div id="Head"/>
<div id="Body" class=" sz940 " itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="itemscope">
<div id="TopPanelDF">
<div id="CenterPanelDF">
<div id="CenterPanel" class=" ebaylocale_en_US ebay_longlngsite ">
<style> /* PicturePanel */ #PicturePanel div.img { border:1px solid #ccc; background-color:white; } /* BuyBox */ .actPanel  { border-top:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-right:1px solid #ccc; } .watchListCmp { border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-right:1px solid #ccc; } </style>
<h3 class="vi-inheritstyl">
<div id="vi_sme_prmts_bnr_cntr1" class="vi-sme-ss-v1">
<!-- Placement 100005 -->
<!-- Placement 100011 && 100012 -->
<div id="CenterPanelInternal" class="">
<div id="PicturePanel" class="pp-c">
<h3 class="g-hdn">Picture Information</h3>
<div class="pp-ic pp-ic300">
<div class="l-shad lftd img img300">
<table class="img img300">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="img img300">
<div id="test">
<script type="text/javascript">var sPT = new Date().getTime(),picTimer,picTimer1,picTimer2;</script>
<a id="linkMainImg" style="display: block; cursor: default; text-decoration: none;" href="javascript:;">
<div id="mainImgHldr" class="" title="Journeys-Edge-Deluxe-Manicure-Set-with-Deluxe-Carrying-Case" style="width: 300px; background-image: none; cursor: pointer;">
<!-- <span id="mainImgHldr" style="display: inline-block;"> -->
<img id="icThrImg" class="img img300 vi-hide-mImgThr" alt="Image is loading" imgsel="0" src="http://ir.ebaystatic.com/pictures/aw/pics/globalAssets/imgLoading_30x30.gif" style="display:none;"/>
<img id="icImg" class="img img300" alt="Journeys-Edge-Deluxe-Manicure-Set-with-Deluxe-Carrying-Case" clk="0" onload="picTimer=new Date().getTime();" style="" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/eHAAAOSwLzdWS4C8/s-l300.jpg" itemprop="image" mskuskip="false"/>
<!-- </span> -->
</div>
</a>
```

The "src" value is: http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/eHAAAOSwLzdWS4C8/s-l300.jpg (this is the only known value)

The value (ID) I am trying to obtain with this method is:

.//*[@id='PicturePanel']/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/a/div/img[2] (this is the XPath to element)

Comment: I didn't understand you question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a different XPATH.

The id will (usually) be unique, so it makes more sense to look for an element using the id attribute.

UPDATE:
You can retrieve the ID by using an XPATH that looks like this:

```
//img[@src = "http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/eHAAAOSwLzdWS4C8/s-l300.jpg"]/string(@id)
```

In case the result has more than one elements, you will get a sequence.

Comment: Sorry but I tried this and it says XPath is invalid. IS there suppose to be double quotes around http part? Where can I learn more about this syntax?

Comment: Check this for start: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp
Can you provide an example from the HTML you are trying to parse so I can give a more accurate answer?

Comment: The answer still stands. I made an edit to make it more accurate to the updated example. You don't need the whole xpath to the element to find the id. I believe your XPATH doesn't work because the XML is broken. But try my updated answer, maybe you will have more luck.